# Notebook getting loud when I watch full screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics, fullscreen

I have a 1.5 year old notebook from Tuxedo (with 16 GB RAM and a 4-core i7 processor) and a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system on it. Since some time the notebook is getting a bit louder (which is normal after some time I guess).

But it is getting really loud as soon as I watch something in full screen. Especially in youtube (even with medium quality settings) I have to turn the volume very loud to still hear the tone...

I am wondering what might cause the notebook to suffer so much from a full screen video. The hardware should really be good enough for this kind of application.

Furthermore I also have a GraphicCard (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M). I already tried different settings with this graphic card (switch it off, use it with highest performance, auto, adaptive) but I cannot spot a difference... The temperature of it is usually between 48 and 51 °C. Also the temperature of the other device is not looking suspicious to me (but I am not 100% sure).

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be or how I could solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "loud"?  As in the fan starts running at high speeds?

Comment: Ja exactly. I think it must be the fan...

Comment: I now installed Ubuntu budgie 18.04 and I have the feeling it got a bit less loud. Probably I should get some new cooling paste if it gets louder again.

Comment: Paste is complicated. Try compressed air to clean out all dust and lint first. Also a new fan can be 20 dollars and old one might be defective.